# Temporary normal mode doesn't wait for the command

Tags: autocompletion, insert-mode

When I press <kbd>C-o</kbd> in insert mode, the expected behaviour is that vim will wait for me to execute a single command and then returns to insert mode. Usually, after pressing <kbd>C-o</kbd> I have all the time in the world to enter the command. However, with my current setup the temporary normal mode triggered by <kbd>C-o</kbd> only lasts for a second and then falls back to regular insert mode. I have narrowed the problem down to the [coc.vim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) plugin so it probably has to do with how autocompletion works. Could there be, for instance, an option to increase the time vim waits before returning back to insert mode?

Comment: Maybe an `InsertLeave` autocommand? You could set `'verbosefile'` to something then `:set verbose=9`. Reproduce the problem and check whether there are any clues in the file you specified. If not bump up `'verbose'` to 12 and try again.

Comment: I think you're right. By scanning a verbosefile I did find an InsetLeave autocommand:  `Executing InsertLeave Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call s:Autocmd('InsertLeave', +expand('<abuf>'))`